# Is nvidia tensorflow docker image available with python 3.6 or 3.7?

Tags: tensorflow, python-3.6, nvidia-docker

The image at https://ngc.nvidia.com/catalog/containers/nvidia:tensorflow uses python 3.5. Is a python 3.6 or 3.7 image available so I don't have to change all f-strings to Python 3.5 format?

Comment: You can check this link (https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/22292)

Answer (score 0):

Not at the moment. All NVIDIA TensorFlow images are released to that location, and they only support python 2.7 and 3.5 at the moment.

New releases are documented here: https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/frameworks/tensorflow-release-notes/index.html